# Why don't we need objects to store string data?

Tags: c++, string, class, oop

In C++, if string is a class, why do we not need the dot operator or an object to store data in a string?

Classic string:

```
string str = "ABC";
```

Why can we directly pass ABC using " " instead of doing it like

```
string str;

str.data = "ABC";
```

But we need to use objects to access the functions.
Example:

```
str.length();
```

Why do we do this?

Is string some special kind of class?

Comment: In this case it's a constructor. But C++ allows you to overload operators which can make it look you are manipulating the object without methods, but this is just syntactic sugar to call methods on the object.

Comment: `std::string` is not a special kind of class, it's a very ordinary kind of class. I suspect that you're familiar with some other language and would benefit from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string str = "ABC";` is not assignment. It is construction. Specifically it calls the `std::string` constructor taking a `const char *` argument.

It's the *same* as doing

```
string str("ABC");
```

just different syntax.

Assignment also works. You do this:

```
string str;
str = "ABC";
```

See also:

[Copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

[std::string constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

[std::basic_string::operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)

Comment: Note that assignment also works though: `str = "DEF";`.

Comment: So, "ABC" is just the const char argument?

Comment: @AtharvaPatwardhan Yes.

Answer (score 2):

[std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has a constructor like this:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s.

But the important point to note is that this constructor is not `explicit`, thus the compiler can do implicit conversion of null terminated character string during constructor call.

For example, following code compiles without any issue:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int) {}
};

int main() {
    Foo f = 10;
}
```

It won't compile if the constructor is written as:

`explicit Foo(int) {}`

Comment: So if the string value is the const char argument and the second argument is mostly NULL, what do I need to assign to initialize the second argument? I mean to ask what (if necessary) to be passed as the const Allocator?

Comment: Seconds argument is not null, it is the default one. All standard containers are allocator aware containers, that is they give us option to pass custom allocator if the default one is not suitable for us. You don't have to think about allocator parameter unless you are doing really advanced works.

Answer (score 0):

In **C++** a string literal is not a `std::string`, but a **C** style character array(`char[N]`). And yes `std::string` or any other 3rd party string type that you may see is a class with a converting constructor accepting character arrays as input. More precisely, `std::string` is a **type alias** for an instansiation of the **template** `std::basic_string`. In short words, before you can do anything with a string literal, you'd better convert it to a string:

`std::string{"ABC"}.size()`

Or you will have to switch to **C** API which is not recommended for beginners:

```
strlen( "ABC")
```